# google maps not showing correct size when called with ajax

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use a google map on a website that is pulling the content with ajax (smartAjax plugin). However, the map is placed on the "Contact Us" page and if I call this page first time, the map shows up in full, if I click back to i.e. "Our Concept" and then again on "Contact Us", the map shows up only partly. I fight this for weeks now and I really can not get any help on this.

Is anybody out there that can have a look here and might tell me what I can do to make the map appear in full after it was called with ajax?

Here it is:
[Please view Website here.](http://mark-i-mark.com/lab/eys/public/ajax1.html)

I would appreciate any help.

Cheers

**UPDATE**
solution was posted by jayarjo

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.setCenter(point); // be sure to reset the map center as well
});
```

This is what you have to include when using ajax and it works beautifully.

Comment: You should use the dev tools on your browser - for instance, get Firebug for firefox, or press 'F12' in chrome. There are several errors thrown by your javascript code - one of these relates to google map co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0):

As I have written in my comment, your javascript code has several bugs. If you fix these, it is likely that this problem will also be fixed.

However, a quick hack is to write the following line:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

somewhere in your code, just after the user changes to the 'contact us' tab.

Comment: That's not a hack. It's the only way of telling the API that the map is now visible and its record of the size needs to be updated.

Comment: somewhere in my code is not specific enough for me, sorry. there is a lot of code. to what code do you refer to?

Comment: Can anybody please tell me where to paste this code. I tried a few places without any success.

Answer (score 0):

You can try modifying the map `initialize()` function. Don't initialize the `map` each time links are clicked.

```
var map;
function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
}
```

Comment: NO, unfortunately it is all the same. always showing only a part of the map and from that other solution (above) I have no idea where to paste that code snippet. Is it really so hard to use a google map in combination with ajax. I though the entire world is doing it.....

Comment: There is an `initialize` function in your code. Didn't you write that? Google map works absolutely fine with Ajax anyways.

Comment: I was not talking about your solution when I said that I don't know where to paste it. I mend the solution from Oliver. I tried your version and it was the same as before, the map was only showing partly. Anyway, I updated my question already because there was a working solution.